# Call Different Method in reactive pipeline

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, reactive

I have a use case where I have to call two different methods in a reactive pipeline Java 8 on a post-API call.

1st Method:
will insert data in a master table and will return the pk of that table insertion.

2nd Method:
this method will insert data in the mapping table which will use the pk received from 1st method.

I try to do that Mono.zip, but that did not work as Zip is calling both methods simultaneously and is not able to pass method 1 output to 2nd method input.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample ? What your calls look like ? Your use-case looks like it can be managed by *flatMap*. If you want the pipeline to return both results, you can : `method1.flatMap(result1 -> method2(result1.pkey()).map(result2 -> Tuples.of(result1, result2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using the `map` or `flatMap` operator, depending on what type of repository you have - reactive or not reactive.

Here is examples for both cases:

```java
public class YourService {
    private final YourRepository repository;
    private final YourReactiveRepository reactiveRepository;

    void doAction() {
        Mono.fromCallable(() -> repository.saveToMainTable("main data"))
            .map(mainTableId -> repository.saveToSecondaryTable(mainTableId, "secondary data"))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .subscribe();
    }

    void doActionWithReactiveRepository() {
        reactiveRepository.saveToMainTable("main data")
            .flatMap(mainTableId -> reactiveRepository.saveToSecondaryTable(mainTableId, "secondary data"))
            .subscribe();
    }

    interface YourRepository {
        int saveToMainTable(String someData);
        boolean saveToSecondaryTable(int mainTableId, String someData);
    }

    interface YourReactiveRepository {
        Mono<Integer> saveToMainTable(String someData);
        Mono<Boolean> saveToSecondaryTable(int mainTableId, String someData);
    }
}
```

You can read more [about map here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and [about flatMap here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: Thans a lot @Yevhenii Semenov , it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be returning only one element in a new stream, you can use map but if you are going to return multiple elements, each as new streams, you can use flatmap.

Here is a helpful video that is easy to understand: [map vs flatmap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwvlS3ViGFQ)

Comment: my problem is not on map and flatmap level. in the call chain of two method , one method output will be the input of other method in a stream operation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).